# setSrc: of DOMHTMLImageElement does not change the Image in WebView

Tags: html, macos, cocoa, webkit

I am facing some issues while changing the images on a WebView dynamically. I am trying to achieve this by changing the `src:` attribute of the Image tag. Here is what I am doing currently.

1) Identify all the Image Tag's in the WebView

```
   [[WebView mainFrameDocument] getElementsByTagName:@"IMG"]
```

2) The above code will give me a `DOMNodeList`

3) I loop through all the Image Nodes and try to change the src to some local path.

```
   [(DOMHTMLImageElement*)node setSrc:newPath];
```

Please Note I'm making use of a file url for the src above which is of the format `file:///Users/Desktop/File.png`

Although I am able to see the src: change in the WebView (by printing the `innerHTML`). I do not see the new image on the WebView. The image seems to show up only if a reload the entire WebView using `loadHTMLString:`

Can some one please let me know if its possible to reload the image without having to reload the entire WebView.

Greatly appreciate the Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little bit of experimentation i figured out what I was doing wrong. Also i feel I had failed to add this crucial bit of information in my question.

I was loading the web view from a string in the following fashion.

```
[[WebView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlString baseUrl:[NSURL UrlWithString:@"http://"]];
```

Here due to the presence of baseUrl I feel the local file url (`file://`) was invalidated due to which the Images never got loaded. If i changed the above code as bellow I found the images to get rendered immediately when I called `setSrc:`

```
 [[WebView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlString baseUrl:nill];
```